# How to deal with Unicode replacement character � (0xFFFD / 65533) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode

I was hardly even aware that the Unicode replacement character (�) existed a week ago. Now I'm learning that there seems to be some very special and strange logic surrounding it at least in SQL. For example:

```
select replace(N'bl' + NCHAR(65533) + N'rt', NCHAR(65533), N'X')
```

returns bl�rt instead of blXrt. And:

```
select CHARINDEX(NCHAR(65533), N'b' + NCHAR(65533) + N't')
```

returns 0 instead of 2. I'm just trying to determine which strings in a table contain this character, and I can't find a straightforward way to do it. The treatment of this character is so strange, there must be more I can learn about it. Where is the behavior defined, and more specifically, what is the easiest way to locate strings in an MS SQL Server database that contain this character?

**EDIT**
For anyone experimenting with answers, I suggest testing your answer on the following data:

```
create table Test([Value] nvarchar(100) not null)
insert into Test([Value]) values('b' + NCHAR(65533) + 't')
insert into Test([Value]) values('b?t')
insert into Test([Value]) values('bat')
```

Comment: Does this depend on the collation of the database or table? Just out of curiosity, what collation are you using?

Comment: The column is nvarchar(100) (so it's Unicode) and doesn't have a specific collation applied, so I guess it's picking up the collation from the database. The database collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS.

Comment: @Jodrell It has to do specifically with TSQL to the extent that I presume I could identify a string containing this character in C#, but I can't do so in simple TSQL code because it's batch oriented.

Comment: I've changed my mind, I think you are exposing a unsatisfactory edge case.

Comment: curiously `SELECT CHARINDEX(NCHAR(65533), NCHAR(65533));` is correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Krzysztof Kozielczyk wrote that the valid unicode characters need to be cast into a binary string in order to be replaced, so that may be the answer to your initial question.

```
SELECT REPLACE(N'test' + NCHAR(65533) 
COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, NCHAR(65533) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, '')
```

The above code also points to how to locate strings with valid unicode characters, but it's a workaround rather than a solution. [source](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/385082/replace-function-does-not-work-with-valid-unicode-characters-above-65500/)

Comment: Being explicit about the collation does seem to make all the functions work as desired.